# Plac object at absolute position over TabbedPage in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like to display button with absolute screen position (left bottom corner) over TabbedPage in xamarin forms.

I have seen third party libraries providing TabbedView over which absolute layout can be implemented, but they are payware and bad so I would like to stay with TabbedPage.

Is it even possible to place something at absolute position over tabbed page? Or if it isn't how can I achieve similar result?

Comment: You can place a "FAB" within the DataTemplate's ContentPage, This will, of course, produce a separate instance of the FAB within each page... Otherwise you would need to subclass TabbedPage and custom code a FAB in that class.